# Inequality for Integration of Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms, geometric-measure-theory

I'm reading Demailly's 'Complex Analytic and Algebraic Geometry' on page 145. Let $K$ be a compact set and $\Theta$ be a positive current of order $0$ of bidimension $(p,p)$ and $\beta = dd^c|z|^2$. Then, he claims there are constants $C_i$ such that $$C_1\|\Theta\|_K\leq \int_K\Theta\wedge\beta^p\leq C_2\|\Theta\|_K$$

My Question:

1. How to get this inequality?(Especially the left part)
2. In general, do we have the Cauchy-like inequality for differential forms? i.e. $|\int\alpha\wedge\beta|\leq \int|\alpha\wedge\beta|\leq \|\alpha\|\|\beta\|$. I don't even know how to define the norm in a proper way.

[image]

Comment: Yes, $\left|\int_M\phi\right| \le \int_M |\phi|$ is correct (where we interpret the right-hand side as the integral of a density, rather than of a top form). With regard to your other inequality, assuming you have a volume form to define inner products, then from $\int_M\alpha\wedge\beta = \int_M \alpha\wedge\star(\star\beta) = \langle\alpha,\star\beta\rangle$ you should get somewhere.

Comment: @TedShifrin $\alpha$ is not a top form. Is there any way to define $\|\alpha\|$ to make the Cauchy inequality work?

Comment: I have given you a standard definition of the inner product on forms of any degree.  This is in all standard textbooks that deal with forms on Riemannian manifolds (e.g., Hodge theory). Once you have an inner product, Cauchy-Schwarz is automatic, is it not?

Comment: For the left part, I think, by the definition of $\beta$, $\int_K\Theta\wedge\beta^p$ is of form $C\sigma_\Theta$, where $C>0$ and $\sigma_\Theta$ is the trace measure of $\Theta$. And we know the total mass is bounded by the trace measure in rough sense. For the right part, I haven't tried but this probably follows by  a simple calculation, where $C_2$ must be an upper bound of the coefficients of the current $\Theta$.

Comment: I said $C\sigma_\Theta$ above but $C\int_K\sigma_\Theta$ would be more exact notation.